# añadir validacion a formulario

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

buen dia. me gustaria que me ayudaran con la validacion de un formulario, estoy aprendiendo de programacion ahora y estoy estancado en la validacion de este formulario lo tengo creado de esta manera.

modal para insertar.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalj" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <br />
  <div class="x_panel">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Añadir Jugador</h4>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="alert alert-danger text-center" style="display:none;" id="error">
        <strong>Adventencia: </strong>Debe completar todos los campos
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-success text-center" style="display:none;" id="exito">
        <strong>Felicidades: </strong>Su registro ha sido guardado
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="modal-body">

<form data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask" method="post" id="forminsertar" name="forminsertar" role="form">

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
<input required="required"  type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left"  name="jNombre" id="jNombre" placeholder="Nombre">
<span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
<input required="required" type="text" class="form-control" name="jApellido" id="jApellido" placeholder="Apellido">
<span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 xdisplay_inputx form-group has-feedback">
<input required="required" type="date" class="form-control has-feedback-left" name="jFecha" id="jFecha" placeholder="Fecha Nacimiento" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status4">
<span class="fa fa-calendar-o form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span id="inputSuccess2Status4" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">

<input required="required" type="text" class="form-control" name="jCedula" id="jCedula" data-inputmask="'mask' : '999-9999999-9'" placeholder="Cedula">
<span class="fa fa-credit-card form-control-feedback right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
<input required="required" type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" name="jCiudad"  id="jCiudad" placeholder="Ciudad">
<span class="fa fa-building-o form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
<input required="required" type="text" class="form-control" name="jDireccion" id="jDireccion" placeholder="Direccion">
<span class="fa fa-home form-control-feedback right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
<input required="required" type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" name="jEstatura" id="jEstatura" data-inputmask="'mask' : '99'" placeholder="Estatura">
<span class="fa fa-unsorted form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
<input required="required" type="text" class="form-control" name="jTelefono" id="jTelefono" data-inputmask="'mask' : '(999) 999-9999'" placeholder="Telefono">
<span class="fa fa-phone form-control-feedback right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<select id="jrefEquipo" name="jrefEquipo" class="form-control has-feedback-left" required>
<option value="" selected>Sin Equipo</option>
<?php do { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_DatosEquipo["idEquipo"]?>" ><?php echo $row_DatosEquipo["eNombre"]?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_DatosEquipo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DatosEquipo));
?>
</select>
<span class="fa fa-users form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>


<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">

<input required="required" type="text" class="form-control" name="jNumero" id="jNumero" data-inputmask="'mask' : '999'" placeholder="Numero Chaqueta">
<span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<select id="jrefPosicion" name="jrefPosicion" class="form-control has-feedback-left" required>
   <option value="" selected>Sin Posicion</option>
   <?php do { ?>
   <option  value="<?php echo $row_DatosPosicion["idPosicion"]?>" ><?php echo $row_DatosPosicion["pPosicion"]?></option>
   <?php
} while ($row_DatosPosicion = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DatosPosicion));
?>
</select>
<span class="fa fa-sort-numeric-asc form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group ">
<input  required="required" type="text" class="form-control" name="jImagen" id="jImagen" placeholder="Imagen">
<span class="fa fa-image form-control-feedback right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
<input required="required" type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" name="jEmail" id="jEmail" placeholder="Email">
<span class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
<input required="required" type="text" class="form-control" name="jContraseña" id="jContraseña" placeholder="Contraseña">
<span class="fa fa-lock form-control-feedback right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">enviar</button>
                </span>
</div>

      <div class="form-group">

      </div>
      <div class="ln_solid"></div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="reset">Limpiar</button>
          <button id="aceptar_jugador" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>


</div>
</div>
</div>
```

y este es el insert

```
<?php

    $jNombre = $_POST['jNombre'];
    $jApellido = $_POST['jApellido'];
    $jFecha = $_POST['jFecha'];
    $jCedula = $_POST['jCedula'];
    $jDireccion = $_POST['jDireccion'];
    $jCiudad = $_POST['jCiudad'];
    $jTelefono = $_POST['jTelefono'];
    $jEstatura =$_POST['jEstatura'];
    $jNumero = $_POST['jNumero'];
    $jrefEquipo = $_POST['jrefEquipo'];
    $jrefPosicion = $_POST['jrefPosicion'];
    $jEmail = $_POST['jEmail'];
    $jContraseña = md5($_POST["jContraseña"]);

    $jregistro=date('Y-m-d');




    $sql="INSERT into tbljugadores (jNombre, jApellido, jFecha,  jCedula, jDireccion, jCiudad, jTelefono, jEstatura, jNumero, jrefEquipo, jrefPosicion, jEmail, jContraseña, jregistro)
            values ('$jNombre','$jApellido','$jFecha','$jCedula','$jDireccion','$jCiudad','$jTelefono','$jEstatura','$jNumero','$jrefEquipo','$jrefPosicion','$jEmail','$jContraseña','$jregistro')";
    echo mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 ?>
```

este es el js

```
$("#jugador-add").click(function () {
            $("#myModalj").modal();

             $("#aceptar_jugador").unbind('click');
                    $("#aceptar_jugador").click(function () {


                        var jNombre = document.getElementById("jNombre").value;
                    var jApellido = document.getElementById("jApellido").value;
                    var jFecha = document.getElementById("jFecha").value;
                        var jCedula = document.getElementById("jCedula").value;
                        var jDireccion = document.getElementById("jDireccion").value;
                      var jCiudad = document.getElementById("jCiudad").value;
                        var jTelefono = document.getElementById("jTelefono").value;
                        var jEstatura = document.getElementById("jEstatura").value;
                        var jNumero = document.getElementById("jNumero").value;
                        var jrefEquipo = document.getElementById("jrefEquipo").value;
                        var jrefPosicion = document.getElementById("jrefPosicion").value;
                        var jEmail = document.getElementById("jEmail").value;
                        var jContraseña = document.getElementById("jContraseña").value;

                        if ( jNombre == "" || jApellido == "" || jFecha == "" || jCedula =="" || jDireccion =="" || jCiudad =="" || jTelefono =="" || jEstatura =="" || jNumero =="" || jEmail =="" || jContraseña =="") {
                        alert("Error: Todos los campos son obligatorios.");

                      } else {
                           $("#myModalj").modal('toggle');

                        var params = {jNombre, jApellido, jFecha, jCedula, jDireccion, jCiudad, jTelefono, jEstatura, jNumero, jrefEquipo, jrefPosicion, jEmail, jContraseña}

             $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'jugador-insert.php',
                    data: params,
                    async:true,

                        success: function(respuesta) {

                            alert("Informacion: Jugador creado correctamente!");
                            location.reload();
                                 }

                });
                }
                });
            });
```

el me funciona perfecto pero quiero agregar la validacion de bootstrap que cubre el input de rojo y no se como hacer el codigo para que funcione cuando le de a enviar. ya que solo tengo la validacion del navegagor.

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar esta librería de **jQuery Validation** para hacer la validación de los datos:

https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Úsalo de esta manera, reemplaza el javascript que tienes actualmente

```
function success(element) {
    $(element).removeClass('form-control-danger');
    $(element).addClass('form-control-success')
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-danger');
    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
}

function danger(element) {
    $(element).removeClass('form-control-success');
    $(element).addClass('form-control-danger');
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success');
    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-danger');
}

$("#jugador-add").click(function() {
    $("#myModalj").modal();

    $.validator.setDefaults({
        errorElement: "span",
        errorClass: "form-control-feedback",
        highlight: function(element) {
            danger(element)
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            success(element);
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (element.parent('.custom-control').length || element.prop('type') === 'checkbox' || element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });

    $('#forminsertar').validate({
        rules: {
            'jNombre': {
                required:true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'jNombre': {
                required: "Ingrese el nombre"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                url: $(form).attr('action'),
                type: $(form).attr('method'),
                dataType: 'json',
                data: form.serialize(),
                beforeSend: function(){
                   //Aqui puedes agregar el loading o algo por el estilo
                },
                success: function(data){
                    alert("Informacion: Jugador creado correctamente!");
                    $('#myModalj').modal('hide');
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Y Reemplaza el código HTML que tienes actualmente por este...

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalj" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <br />
            <div class="x_panel">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Añadir Jugador</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="alert alert-danger text-center" style="display:none;" id="error">
                    <strong>Adventencia: </strong>Debe completar todos los campos
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-success text-center" style="display:none;" id="exito">
                    <strong>Felicidades: </strong>Su registro ha sido guardado
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="jugador-insert.php" method="post" id="forminsertar" name="forminsertar" role="form">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                        <input required="required" type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" name="jNombre" id="jNombre" placeholder="Nombre">
                        <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                        <input required="required" type="text" class="form-control" name="jApellido" id="jApellido" placeholder="Apellido">
                        <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 xdisplay_inputx form-group has-feedback">
                        <input required="required" type="date" class="form-control has-feedback-left" name="jFecha" id="jFecha" placeholder="Fecha Nacimiento" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status4">
                        <span class="fa fa-calendar-o form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span id="inputSuccess2Status4" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">

                        <input required="required" type="text" class="form-control" name="jCedula" id="jCedula" data-inputmask="'mask' : '999-9999999-9'" placeholder="Cedula">
                        <span class="fa fa-credit-card form-control-feedback right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                        <input required="required" type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" name="jCiudad" id="jCiudad" placeholder="Ciudad">
                        <span class="fa fa-building-o form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                        <input required="required" type="text" class="form-control" name="jDireccion" id="jDireccion" placeholder="Direccion">
                        <span class="fa fa-home form-control-feedback right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                        <input required="required" type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" name="jEstatura" id="jEstatura" data-inputmask="'mask' : '99'" placeholder="Estatura">
                        <span class="fa fa-unsorted form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                        <input required="required" type="text" class="form-control" name="jTelefono" id="jTelefono" data-inputmask="'mask' : '(999) 999-9999'" placeholder="Telefono">
                        <span class="fa fa-phone form-control-feedback right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <select id="jrefEquipo" name="jrefEquipo" class="form-control has-feedback-left" required>
                            <option value="" selected>Sin Equipo</option>
                            <?php do { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row_DatosEquipo[" idEquipo "]?>">
                                <?php echo $row_DatosEquipo["eNombre"]?>
                            </option>
                            <?php
                            } while ($row_DatosEquipo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DatosEquipo));
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <span class="fa fa-users form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">

                        <input required="required" type="text" class="form-control" name="jNumero" id="jNumero" data-inputmask="'mask' : '999'" placeholder="Numero Chaqueta">
                        <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <select id="jrefPosicion" name="jrefPosicion" class="form-control has-feedback-left" required>
                            <option value="" selected>Sin Posicion</option>
                            <?php do { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row_DatosPosicion[" idPosicion "]?>">
                                <?php echo $row_DatosPosicion["pPosicion"]?>
                            </option>
                            <?php
                            } while ($row_DatosPosicion = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DatosPosicion));
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <span class="fa fa-sort-numeric-asc form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group ">
                        <input required="required" type="text" class="form-control" name="jImagen" id="jImagen" placeholder="Imagen">
                        <span class="fa fa-image form-control-feedback right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                        <input required="required" type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" name="jEmail" id="jEmail" placeholder="Email">
                        <span class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                        <input required="required" type="text" class="form-control" name="jContraseña" id="jContraseña" placeholder="Contraseña">
                        <span class="fa fa-lock form-control-feedback right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">enviar</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                    </div>
                    <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="reset">Limpiar</button>
                            <button id="aceptar_jugador" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```